# "Please correct my English" checkbox

Tags: feature-request, edits, non-english-speakers

Many people (including me) are not fluent in English. So often my questions have many language "bugs". What about an option on Stack Overflow such as the following:

1. I write a question on a Stack Exchange site.
2. I know that I'm not a native speaker of English, so I check the option "Please correct my language".
3. My post will get a special tag (or whatever other indicator) "Language needs correcting", which makes it visible within a special review queue.
4. Someone (with over 2k reputation or something similar) can see that type of question and, if he understands it, he can choose to correct the language "bugs" (grammar, typos etc.)

After that people can better understand the question, and it's more likely for someone to help and answer it.

Comment: I would argue that all posts are eligible for editing so the problem doesn't really exist. If your post can be understood it will be very quickly edited, if not then no amount of tags could help

Comment: But I still learning of English and want know what of mistakes I made. SO for example is platform where I can learn English and get knowledge about programming.

Comment: If your post is edited, study the changes to see if/when they're language-related.

Comment: @Bart Thanks for editing my question. But there is small amount of people who correct language mistakes. More of then focus on code/formatting than language

Comment: @WooCaSh I have a feeling you're not experiencing this fast editing because your english is already pretty good and easily understandable so people usually leave your posts alone. It makes me ashamed of my own language skills when people with actually quite good english such as yourself say they are not great at english.

Comment: @WooCaSh Ultimately its not within SO's scope to teach English (nor should it be, there are a lot of better places for that). So if your posts are clear already then they are unlikely to be edited. Take it as a compliment

Comment: @WooCaSh If I look at what you posted, it was simply clear. Was it perfect? Nope. So I corrected and rephrased a couple of things. But you're not doing bad at all. As for learning English, it's not SO's goal to teach you that. With a bit more experience you'll pick it up though. You're already doing quite well. And I'm sure users will correct you every now and then. I don't think we need a special option. Those cases that are truly unclear are often a tricky edit as well and you've got to wonder if it's worth the effort, if the OP won't understand it any more.

Comment: @RichardTingle Now my question is edited and you can think that I am skilled :). But if you saw my question before editing and still think that I have good skill of english I need to say "Thanks".

Comment: Just take your time when you post. You have an infinite amount of time before posting. Make it the best, most clear post you possibly can. If there are then a couple of small things to correct, there are a lot of users who are more than happy to do so without a queue.

Comment: @WooCaSh I did indeed see it before Bart's edit. I agree completely with Bart, some minor mistakes but I didn't even have to read it carefully; your meaning was clear.

Comment: Well. You have probably right. So write a answer which I can checked as correct now :)

Comment: @WooCaSh Judging by this question, your English is sufficiently good. If you feel your posts would profit by someone with greater skills polishing the language, what about posting a comment "If somebody can improve my language, an edit would be appreciated"? That would however risk that somebody with lesser skills might have a go at it.

Answer (score 7):

Stack Overflow is a programming community so no one here is going to (at least I hope so) downvote you for grammatical or spelling errors.

If your question is understandable, it will have about as much chance to be answered with language errors as without them. If someone (usually native speaker) would be annoyed by those errors, he will just edit them. There's nothing to be afraid of. Editing someone's post has nothing to do with downvoting.

On the other side, if the language errors made the post hard to understand, what would be a profit from such an option? It would be impossible to fix the post without guessing what the author had in mind. So it would be as much likely to be closed as [NARQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/40354#40354) as without that flag.

If you want such a flag to inform others you're not native speaker - you don't need it either. They already know from the errors you make. (If you make almost no mistakes - then, by definition, you don't need that flag).

Summarizing, I don't see any advantage for you or anyone else from having such a flag.

Comment: +1 for the attitude. I wish everyone felt the same way. I think most people do, though I have come across the occasional situation where a user does not understand that English is not everyone's first language, and assumes the OP is being abrupt or rude. However I think it's a fringe case, and the type of person to react in such a closed-minded way is probably not going to notice the proposed flag anyway. Not to mention it would open the floodgates for more options... "Please correct my leetspeak", "Please correct my attempts at humour"....